# Create Kali LIVE USB from Macbook with persistence

Tags: macos, usb, kali-linux

I'm attempting to create a Kali LIVE USB with persistence from my Macbook.  I'm following [these instructions from Kali](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence)  I can generate the USB and boot into the image.  Selecting "with persistence" does not persist.

Toward the middle of the page we have

> Create and format an additional partition on the USB drive.
> First, let’s create the new partition in the empty space above our Kali
> Live partitions.
>
> end=7gb
> read start _ < <(du -bcm kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso | tail -1); echo > $start
> parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary $start $end
>
> The parted command may advise you that it can’t use the exact start values you specified; if so, accept the suggested value instead. If advised that the partition isn’t placed at an optimal location, “ignore” it. When parted completes, the new partition should have been created at /dev/sdb3; again, this can be verified with the command “fdisk -l“.

However, there is no "parted" command on OS X and the diskutil does not seem to support start and stop.  I would appreciate help in one of two options

1. Please explain how to use `diskutil` to find the start and stop values.
2. Alternatively, a complete instruction set, preferably not using third party, proprietary software.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the persistence so I can update the packages as well, not just storage